# Can you have a Docker registry with credentials?

Tags: docker

Assume I am running a docker registry at `example.com`, i would pull down images by:

```
docker pull example.com:5000/image:1
```

How can I password protect this registry? It might contain confidential code/data.

Answer (score 4):

This is mentioned in [the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#restricting-access). There are several ways to secure a Docker registry. Note that all of them will only work with a TLS-secured registry (otherwise you'd be sending password or other credentials in plain-text, which would not add any security).

#### Authentication within the registry itself

Start by creating a credentials file in htpasswd format:

```
$ htpasswd -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd
```

Then mount this file into your registry container and pass the `REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_*` environment variables:

```
$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/auth:/auth \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd" \
  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm" \
  -e REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

#### Proxy authentication

Use a reverse proxy (like Nginx) running on the host or another container to handle authentication (documented in-depth [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/nginx/)):

```
upstream docker-registry {
    server registry:5000;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name myregistrydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.key;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    location /v2/ {  
        auth_basic "Registry realm";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.htpasswd;

        proxy_pass                          http://docker-registry;
        proxy_set_header  Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout                  900;
    }
}
```

#### External authentication with token server

As you've mentioned username/password protections, one of the solutions above will probably be sufficient for you. For completeness, you can also use authentication with an external authentication provider. The interface that a token server needs to implement is specified [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/), with the necessary configuration options being described [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#auth).